# Is there a way to only have Bootstrap accordion work in mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

Is there a way to have Bootstraps accordion function only in mobile? In desktop, I'd like the content in the panels to show without the outside borders or accordion functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include both versions, but add a responsive utility class to the desktop version to hide it on mobile:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
 // desktop version here
</div>
```

And add corresponding class to the mobile version to show it on mobile:

```
<div class="visible-xs-block">
 // mobile version here
</div>
```

Here is the [documentation for responsive helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering such an old thread, but came across this whilst searching for a quick fix so thought I'd share what I came up with.

`//collapse BS accordions on page load in mobile view, and re-expands if screen size changes to tablet or desktop size
        $(window).on("load resize",function(){
            var screenwidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            if (screenwidth <= 767) {
                  $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
                  $('a[aria-expanded="true"]').addClass("collapsed");
                  $('a[aria-expanded="true"]').attr("aria-expanded", "false");
            }
            if (screenwidth >= 768) {
                  $('#accordion1 .panel-collapse').addClass('in');
                  $('#accordion1 a[data-toggle="collapse"]').removeClass('collapsed');
                  $('#accordion1 a[data-toggle="collapse"]').attr("aria-expanded", "true");
            }
        });`